# How to retro-fit AngularJS in Google AppEngine?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine

I'm working collaboratively on Google App Engine project. Other contributors have committed a basic App Engine project structure:

```
└───src
    ├───main
        ├───java
        │   └───com
        │       └───[...]
        └───webapp
            ├───css
            ├───fonts
            ├───img
            ├───js
            ├───partials
            └───WEB-INF`
```

The `java` directory contains the server-side app written in Java.
The `webapp` directory contains predominantly client-side code including a basic AngularJS app. However it's also home to `WEB-INF` which configures the webapp and is not client-side app code.

If I wanted to start using Yeoman to manage the client-side app and get all the benefits that Grunt and Bower bring, how would I do this? I've only ever scaffolded out Yeoman apps from the beginning and never from a predefined Google App Engine project.

I can think of two options:

1. Remove everything under `webapp` (excluding `WEB-INF`) and run
   Yeoman from within the `webapp` folder. This feels a little
   ungraceful.
2. Separate out the App Engine project from the client-side
   Angular app and scaffold out an Angular app using Yeoman.

To be clear, I'm looking for information on the **means** of introducing Angular using Yeoman, rather than just **end** product of Angular existing in an App Engine app.

Comment: Google has a repo that shows an example, sans-yeoman https://github.com/googlearchive/appengine-angular-guestbook-java

Comment: @Josh - Thanks for responding, but I'm looking for information on the *means* of introducing Angular using Yeoman, rather than just *end* product. I'll edit my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this specific example](https://github.com/Sfeir/hello-world-oauth2-endpoints-angularjs) of an App Engine and AngularJS example.

Perhaps this might be a decent starting point for you to work with.